# Will Debian overwrite Windows 10?

Tags: linux, debian, windows

I currently have Windows 10 on my new dell laptop. I have in the past dual booted Windows 10 with Linux Mint and Ubuntu. I would like to install Debian now.

Will the Debian installation over-write my Windows 10?

In the past when I've installed Linux Mint and Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, I usually get a prompt asking me if I want to install alongside Windows or if I want to overwrite Windows. I am also being asked to find non-free firmware for wifi access during the Debian installation.

Should I proceed with installation and install non-free firmware after Debian is installed? And will this still install Debian alongside Windows? Long story short; I don't want to lose Windows 10. Will this overwrite my Windows?

Answer (score 0):

> Will the Debian installation over-write my Windows 10?

No ,If you choose the manual partitioning, you can  resize/create the new partitions

**Yes , It will over-write your windows 10 if you choose the automatic partitioning**

> Should I proceed with installation and install non-free firmware after Debian is installed?

Yes you can install the non-free software later

You can also download the missing firmware to anther USB to get the wifi working during the Debian install